# Does Serilog captures log automatically when configured with Log Level

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I am using Serilog for the first-time and trying to figure how it works. I am looking at a sample ASP.Net Core application where Serilog is configured. The serilog configuration is being read from Appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "ApplicationName": "app-name",
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": { "pathFormat": "log-{Date}.log" }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Log object is defined in Startup and "**AddSerilog**" is defined in "**ConfigureServices**" Method. But other than that no other log information is present. However when I run the app automatic log files are being generated in the Solution directory.

Question is does Serilog automatically creates those log files?

Comment: `Serilog` will create those log files, if you want to write log to these files, you need to call `Log.Logger.Information("This is Info");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `AddSerilog` in `ConfigureServices` registers a logging provider with Microsoft's [`ILoggingBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggingbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2). This provider ([`SerilogLoggerProvider`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/master/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs#L26)), implements [`ILoggerProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and its `CreateLogger` method, which looks like this:

```
public ILogger CreateLogger(string name)
{
    return new SerilogLogger(this, _logger, name);
}
```

It's clear from this code that Serilog's `SerilogLogger` implements Microsoft's `ILogger` interface.

When the ASP.NET Core framework needs to create a logger object, it uses implementations of `ILoggerProvider` to create instances of `ILogger` by calling `CreateLogger`. With the registered Serilog provider in place, this ends up with ASP.NET Core asking for an instance of `ILogger` and receiving an instance of `SerilogLogger`, which provides a bridge between ASP.NET Core and Serilog.

The RollingFile sink itself creates the configured log file automatically whenever a log event is emitted, with its own logic for creating timestamped files, etc, accordingly.